# MySQL Provider errors in Entity Framework 5.0

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-5

I'm using Entity Framework 5.0 with MySQL 6.8.3

I've already copy both MySql.Data.dll and MySql.Data.Entity.dll to Output folder.
On my PC, I add following code to App.Config:

```
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
    <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data"/>
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

It works fine, but when I bring it to another PC, I must remove that config to make it worked. How can I make it worked without adding or removing that config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out my problem. This issue was due to conflict of MySQL in project and Connector/Net.

For anyone has the same problem with me, just specific the version of MySQL dll in your provider configuration:

```
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
    <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"/>
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

This version should be same as the dll that your project references.